# GUI module not found

Tags: user-interface, jupyter-notebook, simpleitk

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
# To use interactive plots (mouse clicks, zooming, panning) we use the nbagg back end. We want our graphs 
# to be embedded in the notebook, inline mode, this combination is  defined by the magic "%matplotlib notebook".
%matplotlib notebook

import SimpleITK as sitk

%run update_path_to_download_script
from downloaddata import fetch_data as fdata
import gui

# Using an external viewer (ITK-SNAP or 3D Slicer) we identified a visually appealing window-level setting
T1_WINDOW_LEVEL = (1050,500)
```

When I run it in spider 3.2.6 I get:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gui'

Any help would be appreciated.

Code source: http://insightsoftwareconsortium.github.io/SimpleITK-Notebooks/Python_html/30_Segmentation_Region_Growing.html

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a spyder issue.

The [gui module](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/SimpleITK-Notebooks/blob/master/Python/gui.py) is part of the [notebooks repository](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/SimpleITK-Notebooks). Either clone the repository or just download this file. Same goes for the [downloaddata module](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/SimpleITK-Notebooks/blob/master/Utilities/downloaddata.py).